# Why is my code not appending these results?

Tags: python, api

I am  trying to learn how to use api's by writing some code which returns words that you can make from some letters you give it for a game called wordscape.

The code runs without errors but I am getting very confused as to why it only appends some of the correct results, not all of them.

Here is an example of the problem, using a snippet of the code:

```
import requests
test=["we","ew"]
for word in test:
    parameters={"define":word}
    r=requests.get("https://googledictionaryapi.eu-gb.mybluemix.net",params=parameters)
    liste=[]
    if r.status_code==200:
        liste.append(word)
```

Lets say I decide to input the letters `we`, there are 2 possible arrangements of those letters, `ew` and `we`. Both of these are words in the dictionary api I am using, however if you run the above code, it only appends `ew`.

However, if you remove `ew` from `test`, so that it only has `we`, it will append `we`.

What is going on here?

Note: Here is the GitHub for the api: https://github.com/meetDeveloper/googleDictionaryAPI

Comment: don't reassign `liste=[]` on each iteration! (that's a root cause)

Comment: put `liste=[]` before `for word in test:`.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hope this helps!

```py
import requests
test=["we","ew"]
liste=[] #Redeclaring the list inside the loop will eliminate previously stored values and as such the scope of the list should be outside the loop.
for word in test:
    parameters={"define":word}
    r=requests.get("https://googledictionaryapi.eu-gb.mybluemix.net",params=parameters)
    if r.status_code==200:
        liste.append(word)
```

Comment: OP asks `What is going on here?`. An explanation would help.

Comment: Commented beside the answer. Sorry, I am a lazy coder. :P